# Facebook login with devise for rails doesn't return a real email

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, devise, omniauth

I've followed the tutorial on the [wiki at devise to enable facebook login](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview) using omniauth-facebook gem. It works and signs the user in and even creates an account however theres one issue here. The email address returned on facebook login looks kinda like:

```
email="app+5qhaf12fo9.2qucvl4nju.1fcb0eaa3df4187d46d0394cf11d664e@proxymail.facebook.com"
```

I dont think this is how it should be working though - why isnt it returning the right email address here? Please do help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue today, but my app was working fine until then. So, I'm not sure if it was a change by Facebook API or something else.

It looks like that Facebook provides a choice to users hide their e-mail from third parties (http://www.ampercent.com/avoid-sharing-email-address-facebook-games-apps/9685/), but that's strange because I didn't use that option and I'm still having this behavior.

**Edit:** Testing with another facebook account, it seems to be working as expected, returning the facebook user's email.

Comment: Hmmm so its likely to be a temporary issue - I've been facing this problem for the past 3 days now though. I'll give it a check and see if that was the case...